# How does % wildcard exactly work in sql when searching

Tags: mysql, sql, select, wildcard, sql-like

I saw a select statement with something like this in the where part 'LIKE %Blabla%Another%', now I tried it myself and I don't clearly understand how it works. The thing I'm confused about is the % in the middle, I understand how '%Blabla Another%' works, but with the % as a replacement for the space, I got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` means "any sequence of characters, including an empty one". So `LIKE '%Blabla%Another%'` will match, for example `'XYZBlablaABCAnotherPQR'`, `'BlablaAnother'` and `'    Blabla Another           '`

Answer (score 0):

% means any (including none) chars.

If you have a string 'abcdef' it would match e.g 'a%f' since the string start and ends with a and f.

'%b%e%'would also match as it means any string with b and even, in that order, but not necessarily next to each other

Answer (score 0):

With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:

% matches any number of characters, even zero characters.

_ matches exactly one character.

© [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, wildcard characters are used with the SQL LIKE operator.

there are the wild cards in sql  %,_,[charlist],[^charlist].

the % wild cards is a substitute for zero or more characters.

for example

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE City LIKE '%es%';
```

this will selects all customers with a City containing the pattern "es".

so here you can see that the % wild card act as null or space character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a listing of the wildcards that you can use and below some examples.

- **%**: A substitute for zero or more characters
- **_**: A substitute for a single character
- **[charlist]**: Sets and ranges of characters to match
- **[!charlist]**: Matches only a character NOT specified within the brackets

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City containing the pattern "es"

- **SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%es%'**

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City starting with any character, followed by "erlin":

- **SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '_erlin'**

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City starting with "b", "s", or "p":

- **SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '[bsp]%'**

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City NOT starting with "b", "s", or "p":

- **SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '[!bsp]%'**

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Character ranges are not supported in MySQL.